# Cluster dataframe containing hex values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains 2 columns of hex color values. I would like to cluster the dataframe by like colors. I think this should just involve some simple math but I am unsure of where to start. See sample dataset below

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['#f2f1eb','#000000'], ['#9ad9f4', '#ecebe8'], ['#9cd9f3', '#000000'], ['#e3c988', '#ecebe8'], ['#b02e39', '#b02e39']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['hex1', 'hex2'])
```

desired output:

| hex1 | hex2 | cluster1 | cluster2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #f2f1eb | #000000 | 1 | 2 |
| #9ad9f4 | #ecebe8 | 3 | 1 |
| #9cd9f3 | #000000 | 3 | 2 |
| #e3c988 | #ecebe8 | 4 | 1 |
| #b02e39 | #b02e39 | 5 | 6 |

I have tried the following but I think there may be a smarter more pythonic way to go about this

```
def hex_to_rgb(hex_val):
    return mcolors.to_rgb(hex_val)

# Convert hex color codes to RGB values
df['rgb1'] = df['hex1'].apply(hex_to_rgb)
df['rgb0'] = df['hex2'].apply(hex_to_rgb)
kmeans1 = KMeans(n_clusters=10).fit(df['hex1'].tolist())
kmeans0 = KMeans(n_clusters=10).fit(df['hex2'].tolist())
df['cluster1'] = kmeans1.labels_
df['cluster2'] = kmeans0.labels_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to compute the clustering (I've set number of unique clusters to 4 for this example, but probably you want to adjust that):

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

data = [
    ["#f2f1eb", "#000000"],
    ["#9ad9f4", "#ecebe8"],
    ["#9cd9f3", "#000000"],
    ["#e3c988", "#ecebe8"],
    ["#b02e39", "#b02e39"],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["hex1", "hex2"])


def rgb_string_to_tuple(rgb_string):
    if rgb_string.startswith("#") and len(rgb_string) == 7:
        r = int(rgb_string[1:3], 16)
        g = int(rgb_string[3:5], 16)
        b = int(rgb_string[5:7], 16)
        return (r, g, b)


df["rgb1"] = df["hex1"].apply(rgb_string_to_tuple)
df["rgb2"] = df["hex2"].apply(rgb_string_to_tuple)

uniq = sorted(set(df["rgb1"]).union(df["rgb2"]))

# Specify the number of clusters you want:
n_clusters = 4

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, n_init="auto", random_state=42)
kmeans.fit(uniq)
labels = kmeans.labels_

df["cluster1"] = df["rgb1"].apply(lambda x: labels[uniq.index(x)])
df["cluster2"] = df["rgb2"].apply(lambda x: labels[uniq.index(x)])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      hex1     hex2             rgb1             rgb2  cluster1  cluster2
0  #f2f1eb  #000000  (242, 241, 235)        (0, 0, 0)         3         2
1  #9ad9f4  #ecebe8  (154, 217, 244)  (236, 235, 232)         0         3
2  #9cd9f3  #000000  (156, 217, 243)        (0, 0, 0)         0         2
3  #e3c988  #ecebe8  (227, 201, 136)  (236, 235, 232)         3         3
4  #b02e39  #b02e39    (176, 46, 57)    (176, 46, 57)         1         1
```